# Mounting disk images on SSDs of different interfaces

Tags: windows-10, ssd, pci-express, disk-image

I was planning to upgrade my PC's main drive ( local drive(C:)) to something with higher data transfer rates and larger storage capacity. I was going to run an image backup on my current SSD that's linked via an M.2 connector, SATA interface. The convenience of not having to set up an entirely new hard drive from scratch, reestablishing drivers and not needing to reinstall software applications makes the process of upgrading so much easier these days. But if the new SSD is the same connector(M.2), but a **different interface** (such as PCIE), will the image still mount successfully? Or would there be any driver considerations I would have to take into account?
The PC runs on Windows 10, 64-bit. It's also an AMD Ryzen 5 system with the new SSD being a NVMe PCIe Gen.3 x4 .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the image will mount successfully. No need for driver considerations. Windows 10 is very flexible when it comes down to cloning. Just make sure you don’t “upgrade” to a smaller size. (that requires a bit more work)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser! In regards to the edit I just made: try to avoid personnal messages, *especially* in questions and answers. There is a [chat room](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/chat) for informal discussion. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Genuine answer - Fog server if you doing bulk clones - over network. If its one drive to another, aomei backupper free, make a system backup to external drive. then restore it to the drive you want to make destination, resize partitions automatically. free app, not limited by make or vendor( acronis free WD only eg)